# XCode compiler error, with a project built using CMake

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cmake, clang

I'm trying to build a XCode (version 5.0) project that was generated from CMake 3.x.

```
clang compiler version:
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

When I try to build the project

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -arch x86_64 blah blah  -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk  blah blah -Wno-unknown-pragmas -F/usr/local/bin/Debug ;**-std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++** -Wall -MMD -MT blah blah
```

---

I get this error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: ';-std=c++0x'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

---

How can I fix this error?

-std and -stdlib are coming from these project properties:
Apple LLVM 5.0 - Language C++ ==> Dialect and Standard library

How do I set this from CMAKE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly there is no `c++0x` language dialect in Xcode 5, but there is a `c++11` dialect.

These properties can be changed in the CMake project in two ways:

- (I've never managed to do this) by setting `CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_` and then the name of the attribute you see in the Xcode project
- By setting the ''generic'' compiler property `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable

Answer (score 0):

There is a stray semi-colon in that command line:

```
-F/usr/local/bin/Debug ;-std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ 
                       ^
```

So the shell is seeing two commands; the first starts with `c++` and the second with `-std=c++0x`.  Find and remove that semi-colon and it should start working.